# HTTP 401 Unable to create record Twillio PHP sdk 5.16

Tags: php, laravel, twilio

I am using a Twilio account for sending SMS to users. I have installed the SDK by executing the following command.

```
composer require twilio/sdk
```

I'm using the following code snippet to send a message.

```
public function sendSms($data)
{
    // Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
    $account_sid = 'sid';
    $auth_token = 'token';
    $twilio_number = "number";
    $client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
    return $client->messages->create(
        $data['phone'], array(
            'from' => $twilio_number,
            'body' => $data['message'],
        )
    );
}
```

According to Twilio documentation, this code should send the message with my valid credentials, but I am getting the following error.

> [HTTP 401] Unable to create record:
> Authenticate85/var/www/art/api/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Version.php

I have researched this issue, but I got no guidance; any clues? **Note:** I have a balance in my Twilio account.

Comment: `HTTP 401` Is an [Unauthorized Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) you should check your credentials and your permissions.

Comment: Looks like perhaps your credentials aren't correct. The 401 error is unauthorized and the error message says "Authenticate". Are you using the test credentials for this or your real credentials?

Comment: Thanks, guys. I have double check my credentials and my problem is solved now.

Comment: In My case, I had enabled and added credentials at that time it was working fine after that I have disabled an extension. Once again when I have again enabled it shows "[HTTP 401] Unable to create a record: Authenticate" error so, I again added credential and it works perfectly though the credential was the same.

Answer (score 1):

> Twilio Developer Evangelist here. Since this post has 13k+ views and no official answer (hidden in
> comments), I'd like to resolve this for those that have the same
> issue.

As @dwhitz mentions, `HTTP 401` is an [Unauthorized Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) (aka no authorization).

If you run into the same error, that likely means your credentials aren't set up correctly.

---

## Step 1: Locate Credentials

**All requests to Twilio's REST API need to be authenticated**. Twilio supports two forms of authentication (both using HTTP basic auth), so you can pick either option:

**1. Account SID & Account Token**

| Username | Password |
| --- | --- |
| AccountSid | AuthToken |

These can be found on your [Account Dashboard](https://twilio.com/console?_ga=2.244866373.1753793967.1669934527-1111941364.1657213658) on the Twilio Console.

**2. API Keys**

| Username | Password |
| --- | --- |
| API Key SID | API Key Secret |

You can create an API Key within [Settings->API Keys](https://www.twilio.com/console/project/api-keys) on your Twilio console.

---

## Step 2: Secure Credentials

You should now have either an (Account SID + Account Token) or an (API Key SID + API Key Secret). **These pieces of information should be hidden and not publicly available (don't share them with your co-workers or push them to GitHub).**

Secure them by storing them in a way that prevents unauthorized access, like [environment variables](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/functions/variables). Here are examples using the 1st form (Account SID & Account Token).

#### Via Mac/Linux

```
echo "export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID='ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'" > twilio.env
echo "export TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN='your_auth_token'" >> twilio.env
source ./twilio.env
```

Make sure to add twilio.env to your .gitignore

```
echo "twilio.env" >> .gitignore
```

#### Via Windows

```
set TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
set TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=your_auth_token
```

---

## Step 3: Load Your Credentials

**If you're getting the `HTTP 401` error, this is likely the biggest point of failure.** You'll want to make sure you're loading the credentials properly.

Now, this depends on your language, but since this question is in PHP I'll answer it in that language using `getenv()`.

> If you're using another language, check out how you can do it in
> [Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/secure-credentials?code-sample=code-load-credentials-from-environment-variables&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=7.x),
> [C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/secure-credentials?code-sample=code-load-credentials-from-environment-variables&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=7.x),
> [Ruby](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/secure-credentials?code-sample=code-load-credentials-from-environment-variables&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=7.x),
> [Python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/secure-credentials?code-sample=code-load-credentials-from-environment-variables&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=7.x),
> or
> [Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/secure-credentials?code-sample=code-load-credentials-from-environment-variables&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=7.x).

```
$sid = getenv('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID');
$token = getenv('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN');
```

After this, you'll initialize your Twilio Client like so:

```
$client = new Client($sid, $token);
```

PS. There are other ways to [work with environment variables in PHP](https://www.twilio.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-php), so check out this blog post if you'd like to do it another way.

---

## Step 4: Still Not Working?

At this point, if you're still getting `HTTP 401` there's likely something wrong with how you're storing/reading the credentials via environment variables.

To debug, you could add print/echo statements to output the data of your env variables. If no data is present, you might want to do more research on working with environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

In my own case, I figured out my Twilo credit  had exhausted, and so automatically Twilo had suspended my account. I recharged my Twilo account and everything got normal.

Answer (score 1):

> This error is occur during Twilio otp verification ,the reason this error arise when you put wrong Twilio credentials in this case this error occur , to solve this error carefully review your Twilio credentials make this correct hope fully your problem will solve.
> In my case i was trying to verify otp with old incorrect credentials, I just added new credentials after creating new Twilio account my problem solved .
> I hope this work for you too.

Answer (score -1):

I suffered days with this, but believe me it's black magic!
How does the error happen: you copy the token from twilio and it is automatically modified in your clipboard. It also happens so sublime and in notepad.
Solution: on the twilio website enter the browser's debug mode and copy the token through the html div element, so it will be copied correctly to your computer's clipboard.
Someone explain this I don't understand witchcraft.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33574833)